# Timezone Problem in Java / Linux

Tags: timezone

I have an application running in cluster mode (two nodes) under tomcat/Linux.
Unfortunately I've noticed that node1 and node2 have different time settings.
When in a shell I punch "date" I get at both machines the same:

```
  > date  --rfc-2822
    Thu, 22 Oct 2009 15:00:15 +0200
```

I wrote a small java program which only prints the formatted date (and time).

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone; 

public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String millis = Long.toString(time);

    Date date = new Date(time);
    System.out.println("Current time in milliseconds = " + millis + " => " + date.toString());
    System.out.println("Current time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    }
}
```

At one node I am getting:
    Current time in milliseconds = 1256215701981 => Thu Oct 22 13:48:21 GMT+01:00 2009
    Current time zone: GMT+01:00

whereas at the other node I am getting:
    Current time in milliseconds = 1256215779203 => Thu Oct 22 14:49:39 CEST 2009
    Current time zone: Europe/Berlin

Is this a Linux setting or a java setting?
In any case, how can I change this?

Thanks in advance!

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) the source of the default TimeZone may vary with implementation. For your case it seems that one server is using Daylight Savings and the other is not.

Also, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392/java-time-zone-is-messed-up) may be helpful.