# TimeZone.getDefault() in linux differs from user to user

Tags: java, linux, timezone

I have a linux box with two users configured. I also have this piece of Java code:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String millis = Long.toString(time);
Date date = new Date(time);
System.out.println("Current time in milliseconds = " + millis + " => " + date.toString());
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("Current time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

If I run `date` on bash I have the same result for both users:

User 1:

```
$ date
Fri Mar 22 10:02:58 PYST 2013
```

User 2:

```
$ date
Fri Mar 22 10:03:22 PYST 2013
```

However, if I run the same java code I have:

User 1:

```
$ java TimeTest
Current time in milliseconds = 1363957432669 => Fri Mar 22 10:03:52 PYST 2013
Current time zone: America/Asuncion
```

User 2:

```
$ java TimeTest
Current time in milliseconds = 1363957456954 => Fri Mar 22 13:04:16 GMT 2013
Current time zone: GMT
```

So I guess it has something to do with the way java is configured for each user.

I checked for a `TZ` environment variable defined, but there is **no** `TZ` defined for anyone of the users.

Any ideas on why am I getting different values for `TimeZone.getDefault()` for different users on the same Linux box?

JVM:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Distro:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)
```

Comment: Which JVM/distro? Seems like is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392/java-time-zone-is-messed-up

Comment: Interesting, but there's for sure a different configuration for this users as you can see one is PYST and the other is GMT. As you know java get's this information from O.S so the cause of this problem is different configurations for this 2 users. This is than related to some Linux configuration better than java or maybe. Are both users using the same JDK installation? Can you check that please?

Comment: Updated the question with JVM+DISTRO.

Comment: @MarcosMaia hi Marcos. Yes, they're both using the exact same JVM.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably something to do with Locale for the user.

check these variables:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale

Comment: Thanks. Your answer looked promising since I didn't check for locale settings. Now I did and apparently they're the same for both users.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem/solution with two machines:

- Two linux machines set to `UTC`
- one JVM reporting incorrect timezone (ex `CET`)
- the other reporting correctly `UTC`

The problem could be:

- The faulty machine has this symlink: `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris`
- `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris` contains `UTC` information

The cause for this could have been a simple `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime` replacing the contents of `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris` instead of overwriting `/etc/localtime` which was a symlink instead of a file!