# Java doesn't care the system timezone

Tags: java, datetime, ubuntu, timezone, jvm

I'm using tomcat6 on an ubuntu server. I have a problem with Java. It looks like it doesn't take the timezone information from the operating system. I used tzselect command to update my timezone and I've also added that line to my .profile file:

```
TZ='Europe/Istanbul'; export TZ
```

However, while date command gives this output:

```
Tue Jul 22 17:20:31 EEST 2014
```

My tomcat logs are printed with this date:

```
10:20:30,006 INFO  [StatsServiceImpl    ] - runSaveStatsTask::FINISHED::DATE::7/22/14 10:20 AM
```

Where can I configure timezone settings which are used by jvm?

Comment: _Java doesn't care the system timezone_ True because Java is platform independent. ;)

Comment: And now to be constructive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6496/1283847

Comment: Great. Voting to close as dupe, so other readers can find answer easily.