# java program reports wrong timezone on linux(shows IST for Europe/Dublin)

Tags: java, linux, redhat

I get a wrong Time zone value (IST) from the following code. Its from [bugreport](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6456628)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
class simpleTest
{ 
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           System.out.println("Simple test Josh ");

           Date now = new Date();
           DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("\n TIME ZONE :"+ cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
           long nowLong = now.getTime();
           String s = now.toString();
           System.out.println("Value of milliseconds  since Epoch is " + nowLong);
           System.out.println("Value of s  in readable format is " + s);

        }
}
```

With Dublin, the zone is wrong. It shows IST

```
$ java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Dublin simpleTest
Simple test Josh 

 TIME ZONE :Greenwich Mean Time
Value of milliseconds  since Epoch is 1408095007238
Value of s  in readable format is Fri Aug 15 10:30:07 IST 2014
```

This one is okay

```
$ java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Helsinki  simpleTest
Simple test Josh 

 TIME ZONE :Eastern European Time
Value of milliseconds  since Epoch is 1408095025866
Value of s  in readable format is Fri Aug 15 12:30:25 EEST 2014
```

Where does the value **IST**  come from?

I have checked os files like /etc/localtime

```
bash-3.2# cd /etc
bash-3.2# ls -lrt localtime 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Nov 16  2010 localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Dublin
```

/etc/sysconfig/clock

```
bash-3.2# cd /etc/sysconfig/
bash-3.2# cat clock 
# The ZONE parameter is only evaluated by system-config-date.
# The timezone of the system is defined by the contents of /etc/localtime.
ZONE="Europe/Dublin"
UTC=true
ARC=false
bash-3.2# pwd
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392/java-time-zone-is-messed-up

Comment: Where's @JonSkeet and his amazing timezone knowledge when you need him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Irish Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/ist.html), which is the correct timezone for Dublin, is abbreviated as IST.

Unfortunately timezone abbreviations are not unique, as you can see in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) - IST can be resolved into (at least) two other timezones. Timezone abbreviations [are not part of the related ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Abbreviations) and their use is not generally recommended.

In general, [UTC timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) should be preferred when multiple timezones are involved. With UTC each party only needs to keep track of at most one timezone apart from their own. In addition, UTC is not affected by [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) practices, which are normally a source of confusion even for locations with the same [longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude).

Comment: Huh!.  I thought that is wrong as India Standard Time=IST

Comment: Just saw that table. Never thought that way. We are including the timeoffset which is actually more useful.

Comment: Unless there is some context to eliminate some alternatives, timezone abbreviations are useless. Quite honestly, I prefer UTC times...

Comment: I agree. Please add that as recommendation iinto your answer. We decided to use UTC in all logging.  This was for a user visible message (email report)